# Which version of AdventureWorks has a column called CustomerId on sales.vIndividualCustomer?

Tags: sql-server

The [SQL Native Client MOF Files here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh880086) come with a Visual Studio Solution that queries adventure works for testing purposes. One of the first queries that application performs when it is compiled and run is

```
SELECT CustomerID, Title, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Suffix,
    Phone, EmailAddress, EmailPromotion, AddressType, AddressLine1, 
    AddressLine2, City, StateProvinceName, PostalCode, 
    CountryRegionName, Demographics
FROM Sales.vIndividualCustomer
```

This returns the following error on Adventureworks 2008, 2012 and 2014.

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'CustomerID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'Phone'.
```

I downloaded these three AdventureWorks editions off of CodePlex today. For 2008 annd 2012 I downloaded a zip file with an LDF and MDF that I attached via `CREATE DATABASE FOR ATTACH`. For the 2014 version of the database I restored a bak file with `RESTORE DATABASE WITH MOVE.` What file should I be downloading from CodePlex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Which version of AdventureWorks has a column called CustomerId on sales.vIndividualCustomer?

[**SQL Server 2005 version of Adventureworks**](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/4004) has `CustomerId` and `Phone`.

[image]

The schema is changed from 2008 for `Sales.vIndividualCustomer` view :

[image]